# Output is lagging when trying to get lambda and alpha values after running Elastic-Net Regression Model

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, lasso-regression

I am new to R and Elastic-Net Regression Model. I am running Elastic-Net Regression Model on the default dataset, titanic. I am trying to obtain the Alpha and Lambda values after running the train function. However when I run the train function, the output keeps on lagging and I had to wait for the output but there is no output at all. it is empty.... I am trying Tuning Parameters.

```
data(Titanic)
example<- as.data.frame(Titanic)
example['Country'] <- NA
countryunique <- array(c("Africa","USA","Japan","Australia","Sweden","UK","France"))
new_country <- c()
#Perform looping through the column, TLD
for(loopitem in example$Country)
{
    #Perform random selection of an array, countryunique 
    loopitem <- sample(countryunique, 1)
    #Load the new value to the vector
    new_country<- c(new_country,loopitem)
}
#Override the Country column with new data
example$Country<- new_country

example$Class<- as.factor(example$Class)
example$Sex<- as.factor(example$Sex)
example$Age<- as.factor(example$Age)
example$Survived<- as.factor(example$Survived)
example$Country<- as.factor(example$Country)
example$Freq<- as.numeric(example$Freq)

set.seed(12345678)
trainRowNum <- createDataPartition(example$Survived, #The outcome variable
#proportion of example to form the training set
p=0.3,
#Don't store the result in a list
list=FALSE);
# Step 2: Create the training mydataset
trainData <- example[trainRowNum,]
# Step 3: Create the test mydataset
testData <- example[-trainRowNum,]

alphas <- seq(0.1,0.9,by=0.1);
lambdas <- 10^seq(-3,3,length=100) 
#Logistic Elastic-Net Regression
en <- train(Survived~. , 
            data = trainData, 
            method = "glmnet", 
            preProcess = NULL,
            trControl = trainControl("repeatedcv",
                        number = 10,
                        repeats = 5),
            tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha = alphas,
                                   lambda = lambdas)
)
```

Could you please kindly advise on what values are recommended to assign to Alpha and lambda?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what the problem is. Your code runs fine for me. If I look at the `en` object it says:

```
Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using the
 largest value.
The final values used for the model were alpha = 0.1 and lambda
 = 0.1.
```

It didn't take long to run for me. Do you have a lot stored in your R session memory that could be slowing down your system and causing it to lag? Maybe try re-starting RStudio and running the above code from scratch.

To see the full results table with Accuracy for all combinations of Alpha and Lambda, look at `en$results`

As a side-note, you can easily carry out cross-validation directly in the `glmnet` package, using the `cv.glmnet` function. A helper package called `glmnetUtils` is also available, that lets you select the optimal Alpha and Lambda values simultaneously using the `cva.glmnet` function. This allows for parallelisation, so may be quicker than doing the cross-validation via `caret`.

Comment: I have restarted the rstudio and running the above code from scratch as per your advise. it stills keeps on hanging.

Comment: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In lognet(xd, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha,  ... :
  one multinomial or binomial class has fewer than 8  observations; dangerous ground
2: In lognet(xd, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha,  ... :
  one multinomial or binomial class has fewer than 8  observations; dangerous ground
3: In lognet(xd, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha,  ... :

Comment: the en did not show me any output

Comment: Are you loading anything into your environment when you re-start RStudio? (This will happen if you've previously asked RStudio to save the workspace) Or is the environment empty when you start running the above code? The only change I made to your above code was to add `library(caret)` at the start, and everything works fine. Do you have any other packages loaded?

Comment: I have other library, library("tidyr");library("readr");library("tidyverse");library("ggplot2");library("caret");library("glmnet");

Comment: What exactly does it output if you just type `en` after running the code?

Comment: It shows the same as your output.

Comment: So what's the problem? It's doing what you want and telling you the optimum Alpha and Lambda. Or are you saying that the problem is now solved?

Comment: it mention that the value is by default, 0.1 for alpha and 0.1 for lambda? It does not changes at all. What is the best recommended value for alpha and lambda and why? usually lambda show random values

Comment: It does change - `en` first outputs a long list showing you the values of `Alpha` and `Lambda` that have been tested, and what level of Accuracy and Kappa they produce. It only lists the top 250 our of 900 combinations that were tested, but you can see the best model at the top. It then tells you what values gave the highest Accuracy - `" the final values were..."`

Comment: You may get different lambda each time, because you're not setting the seed right before you run `train` - if you do you well get reproducible results.

Comment: You can see the full results in a table via `en$results` - you will probably see that at Alpha=0.1, there's a range of Lambda values that offer the same Accuracy, although all of them are on the low end of the Lambda values that you've tested.